# Invalid request BLR at offset 258 , function HASHMD5 is not defined?

Tags: c#, windows-7, firebird2.5

I am using Firebird 2_5 database with c#,
at inserting data into Firebird databse i have this error please how to solve this r?

```
"FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdCliente.FbException (0x80004005):invalid request BLR at offset 258
function HASHMD5 is not defined
No message for error code 335544932 found"
```

'

Comment: Message for errorcode 335544932 is: "module name or entrypoint could not be found"

Comment: has the cause for this error ever been found?

Answer (score 3):

Firebird itself does not have a function called `HASHMD5`. Firebird also has UDFs (user defined functions) which allow you to add functions (with a library on the search path of the Firebird application, and a definition in the database).

The error message indicates that your database has a UDF called `HASHMD5` defined (and used in a stored procedure, trigger or computed field), but the UDF library is not accessible to Firebird. Reasons might be that it is not on the server, or that the configuration of Firebird disallows access to the UDF library, or the UDF library is 32 bit while Firebird is 64 bit (or vice versa).

By default UDFs are located in the `udf` folder in the firebird installation.

Searching for "firebird udf hashmd5" does not return any relevant results, which suggests that this is not a publicly available UDF and therefor most likely is specific to your company or to the application you are using.