# Firebird sql update command not working in delphi

Tags: sql, delphi, firebird

I'm trying to make a firebird database management using Delphi - RAD Studio X5, but I have a problem every time I execute this command:

```
   update ESTOQUE set QTD='700' where CODIGO='1'
```

I got this message:

```
"[FireDAC][Phys][FB]invalid request BLR at offset 241 function HASHMD5 is not defined unkown error 335544932"
```

And when I run queries commands ( `select * from ESTOQUE`), it works perfectly.

My firebird version is 2.5

My Windows is 8.1 and Windows 10 ( the problem happens in both )

I have the following definition in database functions:
"
DECLARE EXTERNAL FUNCTION HASHMD5
CSTRING(32767) CHARACTER SET WIN1252
RETURNS CSTRING(255) CHARACTER SET WIN1252
ENTRY_POINT 'RetornarHashMD5'
MODULE_NAME 'mylibrary_udf';
"

Neither database adm FlameRobin neither nor delphi application cannot read  mylibrary_udf.dll. How can I do it possible?

Comment: Do you actually have this `mylibrary_udf.dll` in the `udf` folder of your Firebird server? Is it a 32 bit or 64 bit library, is your Firebird install 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: i solved it, the problem was the firebird version.... and mylibrary_udh.dll is into firebird udf folder....
Thanks ....

Comment: yes, mylibrary_udf is into firebird udf folder .... the problem was the firebird version .... I was using the version 2.5, and the correct is the version 2.0, it solve the problem

Comment: UDFs that work with version 2.0, should also work with 2.5; I think it is sooner a 32 bit <> 64 bit problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The error message indicates that your database has a UDF called
>   `HASHMD5` defined (and used in a stored procedure, trigger or computed
>   field), but the UDF library is not accessible to Firebird.

See this answer : [Invalid request BLR at offset 258 , function HASHMD5 is not defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19455485/invalid-request-blr-at-offset-258-function-hashmd5-is-not-defined)

Likely in table `ESTOQUE` has а computed field or trigger BEFORE/AFTER UPDATE that uses an UDF called HASHMD5 to calculate a hash value.

Comment: If this answer is correct (and I think it is) running the update command through a database query tool, i.e. outside Delphi code, should produce the same error.

Comment: @HughJones Not necessarily, maybe the tool uses Firebird embedded and the application firebird server (or vice versa). Or one connects to a 64 bit Firebird and the other to a 32 bit Firebird on the same server. One has the UDF, and the other has not (or it is the wrong bitness), etc, etc.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - Of course I meant connecting to the same server.  The UDF is installed at the server - right?  (or have I forgotten how it works?)

Comment: @HughJones When connecting to the same server it should indeed behave the same. But unfortunately I have seen some questions here and on firebird-support that ultimately were caused by connecting to the wrong server/embedded. However the OP says that running a select does not produce an error while an update does, so different query types, so this discussion might be a bit unnecessary ;)

Comment: That's fine - I just was worried I had forgotten how the UDFs get deployed

Comment: if i disable these triggers,  will i  have problem?

Comment: i tried disable them but i got this message:

Error: *** IBPP::SQLException ***
Context: Statement::Execute( ALTER TRIGGER AIUD_ESTOQUE INACTIVE )
Message: isc_dsql_execute2 failed

SQL Message : -607
can't format message 13:393 -- message file C:\Program Files (x86)\firebird.msg not found

Engine Code    : 335544351
Engine Message :
unsuccessful metadata update
MODIFY TRIGGER failed

Comment: the problem was the firebird version .... I was using the version 2.5, and the correct is the version 2.0, it solve the problem

Comment: First, Happy New Year.
The problem is rather in the bit version of Firebird 32 or 64, not in release version. (see the Mark's comment) I recommend to use 2.5 version (32 or 64 bit) according of version of your UDF library.

Answer (score 0):

Error

> invalid request BLR

most often occurs when is Stored procedures/triggers inconsistency. In your case, the problem may be a trigger bound to Update the table (hence the error occurs only when you update, but not when you select). So check the table Estoque and Check the trigger on before/after update, and if has a stored procedure check it has the right number/order/type of parameters (eg. The trigger calls Stored procedure with 5 parameters, but she has actualy 7 parameters)

Comment: The error code 335544932 means "module name or entrypoint could not be found", which means that a necessary UDF library could not be loaded.

Comment: Thanks for info. So I have to delete my answer?
Someone else may have a problem with invalid request BLR and may not be related to the UDF function.

Comment: I think that is your choice; it might indeed be helpful to people with other "invalid request BLR" even though it doesn't answer this specific question.