# Invalid request BLR at offset 1049 - function ROUNDDEC is not defined

Tags: c#, sql, database, stored-procedures, firebird

First lets mention that I am working on some program that is already using a database from our other program which I haven't built.

So I tried to use stored procedure and here is how that procedure looks like:

```
↑OK
↓VRDOK
↓BRDOK
↓ROBAID
↓CENA_BEZ_PDV
↓KOL
↓RABAT
```

So here is my commmand:

```
using (var command = new FbCommand("NAPRAVISTAVKU", con)
       {
           CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
       })
{
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VRDOK", 33);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BRDOK", 711066);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ROBAID", 1040);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CENA_BEZ_PDV", 0.0);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KOL", 10.0);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RABAT", 0.0);
    FbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        MessageBox.Show(dr[0].ToString());
    }
}
```

So my question is why am I getting this error that `funcion rounddec is not defined`. Is that function supposed to be in database or in my program or other external file? Is there a way to create new function inside my program and call it ROUNDDEC since I know what it needs to do?

Error image [link](http://image.prntscr.com/image/fa48a1b1518d44ffa433e96c9d5999ed.png)

Comment: Nothing in that calls ROUNDDEC - is this an SQL error?

Comment: I added image of error to post. It occurs when it comes to `command.ExecuteReader();`

Comment: Please post the code of the stored procedure. The error itself indicates you are referencing an UDF that either does not exist in the database, or the library containing the UDF is not accessible (does not exist, wrong bitness) on the server. There is no function `rounddec` in Firebird itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid request BLR at offset 258 , function HASHMD5 is not defined?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19455485/invalid-request-blr-at-offset-258-function-hashmd5-is-not-defined)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel How can i see stored procedure definition in Visual Studio, and i checked that post but it is not same (i mean offset) but still checked UDF folder on our server where other program is running normally, and there is no other files except default files that i have on my computer

Comment: It is the same error, the offset refers to the position in the compiled stored procedure, so the fact that the position is different is similar to having the same error on a different line. The cause is the same: your stored procedure is referencing an UDF called `rounddec`, and Firebird either doesn't have the definition in your database, or can't load the associated library (it doesn't exist, the UDF location is restricted, or the library is 32 bit and Firebird is 64 bit (or vice versa)).

Comment: As to how you can find it in Visual Studio, no idea. I suggest you use flame robin to look at your database, or otherwise use select `select RDB$PROCEDURE_NAME, RDB$PROCEDURE_SOURCE from RDB$PROCEDURES where RDB$PROCEDURE_NAME = 'NAPRAVISTAVKU'` to get the body of the stored procedure.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel is it possible that it get confused because i have both 64bit and 32bit firebird on my computer, but we use only 32bit for program (i am normally programming and debugging without any problems even if i have 64bit installed)

Comment: The bitness of your program doesn't matter (unless you are using Firebird embedded in your program), what matters is the bitness of the Firebird server and the UDF library: they must be the same. So if the UDF library is 32 bit, then you must use a 32 bit Firebird server (or, if the UDF library is 64 bit, then you must use a 64 bit Firebird). So if you copied the database from a location where it is working, make sure you copy all UDF definitions other than the default `fb_udf.dll` and `ib_udf.dll`, and make sure you use the same bitness as the Firebird server where the database does work.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I have installed Flame Robin and under functions i can see `ROUNDDEC` and here is image how it looks like: [image](http://image.prntscr.com/image/502ece589da04a60a81be9038110059d.png). So i have that function in DB, so is the problem that he is confused because i have both Firebird x64 and Firebird x86?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel i am just guessing now because i do not know that much about stored procedures and functions (at all), but do i need to write something in my code so i can use that database functions or i can just connect to database and call them just like i did

Comment: That just means the definition exists in the database, it doesn't mean the library containing the UDF (FreeUdfLib.DLL) is accessible to the server.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I saw that FreeUdfLib.dll on my server in Firebird but older version (1.5). Do i need and may i just copy it to my current version 2.1?
EDIT:
Tried it but still the same error.

Comment: If you didn't have `FreeUdfLib.dll` installed yet on your Firebird server, then you should. FreeUdfLib.dll is not part of Firebird; it is a really old library, but it will probably work. However your company should really consider upgrading to more recent versions of Firebird (eg 2.5 or 3.0), and use the built-in functions like `ROUND` instead. A lot of those UDFs are built-in into Firebird these days, removing the need for external function definitions.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel i know but there are reasons why we are not upgrading... Anyway it still doesn't work. I added FreeUdfLib.dll to Firebird_2_1/UDF folder but not working. Then i tried to create Firebird_1_5 folder and UDF inside it and still not working.

Comment: I suggest you mail the Firebird-support list instead. This seems too much like troubleshooting, and Stack Overflow is not really suitable for that.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Can you help me contacting them. I have never used this yahoo groups, and i tried something but it is not working. If you are willing to help me mail me at `aristiccitsira@yahoo.com`

Comment: You just need to send an email to firebird-support-subscribe@yahoogroups.com to subscribe; you can then use email, I never touch the Yahoo Groups webpage if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

ROUNDDEC is part of FreeUDBLib.dll and it is working with 32bit firebird. Problem was I had installed on my PC Firebird 3.0 x64, Firebird 2.1 x64 and Firebird 2.1 x86. My program was built to work for Firebird 2.1 x86, but for some reason, even if I had this DLL in x86 version ULF file, it was not pulling it from it, instead it was checking for UDFs in x64bit version. So solution was to uninstall all versions and reinstall 2.1 x86, then reinstall ddex and firebird.sql and it worked.

I think there is better way to manually set up folder for UDF, but for now I do not know so this was the acceptable solution.